# Element inside loop having last loop value for all ids

Tags: javascript

I have a while loop that loops 6 times, each time its loops a TD element is create as well as setting an id to it, the problem im having is that the id for everysingle one of the TDs is having the last result of the loop.

```
var table = document.getElementById("table_calendar");
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td;
var days_displayed = 1;
while(i<=6){
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = days_displayed;
    td.classList.add("tdd");
    td.id = year+"-"+month +"-"+days_displayed;
    console.log(days_displayed);
    td.onclick = function(){
        alert(td.id);
    };
    days_displayed++;
    i++;
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
table.appendChild(tr);
```

The alert function is showing this for any TD that I click **2018-02-6**

The innerHTML is having different values such as 1 2 3 4 5 6

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try moving your var td inside the while.

Comment: where do `month` and `year` come from?

Comment: This is working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1wfq3fxm/4/

Comment: @messerbill and `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the `id` of the HTML element using `this`:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table_calendar");
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td;
var days_displayed = 1;
var year = "2028"
var month = "02"
var i = 0
while(i<=6){
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = days_displayed;
    td.classList.add("tdd");
    td.id = year+"-"+month +"-"+days_displayed;
    console.log(days_displayed);
    td.onclick = function(){
        alert(this.id);
    };
    days_displayed++;
    i++;
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
table.appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="table_calendar">
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

What happens here is that your `td.id` will return the last element created, because it has been declared as a `var` outside the loop. The scope of `var` is not limited to the block inside `{}`. If you want the variable to be block scoped you have to use `let` instead:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table_calendar");
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var days_displayed = 1;
var year = "2028"
var month = "02"
for(let i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = days_displayed;
    td.classList.add("tdd");
    td.id = year+"-"+month +"-"+days_displayed;
    console.log(days_displayed);
    td.onclick = function(){
        alert(td.id);
    };
    days_displayed++;
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
table.appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="table_calendar">
  </tr>
</table>
```

[What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable)

Greetings